# Method to introduce a new String object into an array of Strings while maintaining the Lexicographical order

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

Side notes:

I want to do this through the Array class, rather than ArrayList.

You can assume the Strings within the String array are already organized in proper lexicographical order (alphabetically listed).

For example:

If the array is -> String[] list = {"Bacon","Cheese","Milk","Pancake","Yogurt"};

And I want to add the String "OJ" into the mix it should look like this:

{"Bacon","Cheese","Milk","OJ","Pancake","Yogurt"}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you against converting to/from arraylist to accomplish the ordering?

Comment: Not even the `ArrayList` class is worth for this functionality. You're seeking for a `TreeSet<String>`. Since you want to keep this using plain arrays (maybe because is a homework), you should look for [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), specifically the algorithm that inserts the element in the bucket and moves all the elements to the right.

Comment: @tieTYT, yes, I would like to do it exclusively through arrays.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I will look into that, thanks. Do you mind typing up a sample bit of code to help me better understand this?

Comment: Since this is homework, I could write an algorithm for you but no code at all.

Comment: Sure. I already have a method written, yet it keeps giving me an error. Can't figure out what's wrong, for the life of me. I figured I might as well think of a fresh approach towards the matter through the help of everyone here.

Comment: @Memorial_Trash then your question should be *I have to do this <explanation>, I have tried this <a short self contained code example from you> but it fails when <foo the bar>* then we will gladly help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(...).

You will have to increase the size of the array. This sounds like homework. TreeSet is an easier class to use.

Comment: `Arrays#binarySearch` will return -1 when used in an element that isn't in the array, so OP should manually seek for the element.

Comment: no it won't (unless the String is supposed to be inserted at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You could append your new entry onto the end of the array and then sort it.

Comment: This is an O(N^2) solution that is not worth since the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method for insertion sort:

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"Bacon", "Cheese", "Milk", "Pancake", "Yogurt", "OJ"};

        InsertionSort in = new InsertionSort();
        list = in.insertSort(list);

        for (String str : list) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    public String[] insertSort(String[] list) {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            String val = list[i];
            int value = list[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && list[j].toLowerCase().charAt(0) > value) {
                list[j + 1] = list[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            list[j + 1] = val;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

The algorithm taken from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort#Java):

```
public static void insertSort(int[] A){
  for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
    int value = A[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while(j >= 0 && A[j] > value){
      A[j + 1] = A[j];
      j = j - 1;
    }
    A[j + 1] = value;
  }
}
```